# How to dynamically call javascript files in an html file with jinja?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I'm trying to dynamically call different javascript files into my HTML by passing the filename through jinja, but it's not working for some reason. My website is a survey/quiz website, and I only want to have one html file for all of the quizzes. Using my variable in jinja doesn't yield any results for some reason. Any idea what to do to make it work?

Here's my python routing.

```
@app.route("/my-quiz")
def myQuiz():
    script =  "myquiz.js"
    return render_template("survey.html", script=script)
```

And here is that info being rendered in HTML.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/script') }}"></script>
```

I haven't really read any documentation on how jinja handles variables so I'm just kinda guessing at how I think it works. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your filename is a static string. It's the same thing as in Python, I could define a variable called `script` and then try to access the variable with `filename = 'scripts/script'` and it wouldn't work.